# BabylonJS scene switching stutters

Tags: babylonjs

### [Live Demo](https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#WGZLGJ#564)

I want to switch between 2 complex scenes for an intro animation. Both scenes load from .gltf or .babylon files and contain camera motion.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that when I switch from scene1 to 2, there's a freeze/stutter before the next scene animation begins.  Once the scene is rendered the switching of scenes continues as normal. It may be hard to spot but there's definitely difference between the first switch and the consequent ones.

I've tried using `scene2.render();` right after loading the scene and it helps a little but it also makes the first scene stutter while it's trying to render both scenes. Is there something that I may be missing about this? I couldn't find an example of an intro with scene switching that works well online. Only camera switch but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

this is because the shaders of the second scene need to be compiled (as they could be different from the ones used in the first scene).

Babylon.js v4 will support parallel shader compilation but this will not be available on all browsers.

The best option could be to force that compilation beforehand:

```
scene1.meshes.forEach(mesh => {
            mesh.material.forceCompilation(mesh);
        });
```